# Should science authors discourage / boycott the recent push for author IDs

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing, journals

In recent years, several organizations (publishers, arXiv, universities) started pushing for systems of a reliable author identification, gaining considerable traction with the recent launch of ORCID. This works by assigning IDs to persons. In some cases, the person itself can then connect his/her articles to the person ID. In other cases, publishers ask / want to ask for the ID upon manuscript submission.

Examples:

- ORCID (supported among others by Spinger, Elsevier, American Physical Society, American Chemical Society, IEEE, Institute of Physics)
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCID
- ResearcherID by Thomson Reuters
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ResearcherID
- Scopus Author ID
  http://www.info.sciverse.com/scopus/scopus-in-detail/tools/authoridentifier

There are some obvious advantages of a precise and machine-readable author identification. These pros are strongly advocated by the big organizations, which are of course very interested. But what about the cons? Before all researchers become obliged to using such IDs, we should discuss the cons and potential problems, and potentially voice our opinion on this issue.

I don't see a big killer-drawback right now, but somehow being tracked by some never-forgetting ID seems quite intrusive.

The biggest drawback might be a loss of privacy. Your research output could then be identified reliably and used for all sorts of data mining. Algorithmic rating of a researcher's output becomes very simple for anyone interested. People could study the "graph of your collaborators" etc.

Somehow I find it preferable to be able to "publish" my publication list myself, i.e., to keep this data in my control - at least to a certain extent. Persons are changing over time. Are you sure that you will still be proud of your last paper in 20 years time? In some extreme cases you might not want to include a certain article in your next grant/job application.

Perhaps this is a little paranoid, but still. What do you think and what are the biggest potential disadvantages?

---

Related texts:
http://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2009/03/11/the-author-id-dilemma/
http://blogs.plos.org/mfenner/author-identifier-overview/

Comment: I think this question is better asked at http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question (or rather request for opinions) is not specific to the math-community. Therefore, it is not on-topic for this site. You could ask this on http://academia.stackexchange.com a similar site, yet dedicated specifically to general question of people working in academia. However, it might be good to phrase it a bit more neutral.   

Comment: You mean we should have the right to pretend that the past never existed? 

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have removed the wikipedia link. It Was perhaps a little over the top.

@Vahid Shirbisheh: No. The point is, 1) that humans can forgive and forget. A database usually doesn't. 2) What are the disadvantages of such a tracking system for the authors?

Comment: Does anyone know if AMS has an opinion on ORCID?

Comment: Since Craig Peterson has edited out the relevant text, I have deleted a previous comment about Godwin's Law.

Comment: @Criag: Honestly, I don't see any disadvantages for myself as an author. But people have different opinions and I'd like to see what others think about this issue.

Comment: While I definitely understand why this question is more suited for academia.stackexchange, I'm a bit curious what pure mathematicians (whatever that means) think of this because mathematics has a very unique culture about listing authors. As far as I know, math is the only field where authors are sorted in alphabetical order. It's not strange for outsiders to wonder how mathematicians assess each co-author's contribution or if math people even care about such a thing. The researcher ID thing may have something somewhere to do with it to some extent.

Comment: @Yuichiro Fujiwara: There are several (pure) mathematicians active on academaia.SE (one of the highest rep users is a mathematician). So asking it there and getting (pure) maths opinions is not at all mutually exclusive.  Indeed, also this co-authorship question cames up there in some form on ocassion, see for example here http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/what-does-first-authorship-really-mean 

Comment: The question (in slightly improved form) can now be found at
http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6060/should-science-authors-discourage-boycott-the-recent-push-for-author-ids .

Comment: @quid Thank you for the interesting link! Yeah, I know we can get ample feedback from mathematicians over there too. It's not like I'm saying this question is appropriate on MO. It's just there's something to this type of question that makes me a bit curious in the context of math as well.

Comment: @Craig Peterson: Thank you for providing the link (and making it more objective)! 
@Yuichiro Fujiwara: No disagreement from me, if it is meant as a general remark (as opposed to trying to make the case for reopening it here).    

Comment: Math Reviews already does this.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion it is crazy (and dangerous!) to compare machine readable author IDs on papers with tattooed ID numbers in concentration camps.  A paper already has a printed name of the author on it.  What is bad about making the different persons called John Doe distinguishable? You are asking to be able to 'unpublish' things?  I find that contradictory to the notion of publishing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have removed the wikipedia link.

Back to the question: I don't say that distinguishing authors is bad and I don't ask about unpublishing things. I am asking, what about the (potential) drawbacks of such an ID system that you are forced to use. Why can't authors resolve possible name ambiguities themselves, and the way they want to do it?

Comment: To add on this: If you can freely choose to publish the list of your articles (under some ID, if you like), for example in order to resolve name ambiguities, there is surely no problem with that and many people will be interested. If you want, you can change the list etc. 

But if all important preprint servers and journals force you to provide a universal ID, that is a different issue - perhaps a bit like imposing a Facebook for researchers.

Comment: Even without any new personal identifiers, and even if I were to publish an incomplete list of my publications, anyone could find a more accurate version of my publication list with an easy search on MathSciNet. That includes a couple of papers that I'd gladly "unpublish" because they present rediscoveries of known results that weren't known to me.  So for me, ID numbers would make no real difference.  It might be different if my name were "John Smith", but I hope that, even then, I wouldn't try to blame another John Smith for my bad papers.

Answer (score 10):

Something tells me this thread's going to get closed at faster than the speed of sound unless OP thoroughly edits the question. But I think it's only good to make it easier to identify researchers eisier and don't see any reason not to.

On a related note, I like the policy of the journals by American Physics Society that allows you to use your native language to display your name on your paper, though currently it's only for Chinese, Japanese and Korean. It's quite difficult to distinguish "similar" names when spelled in the very exotic alphabet, namely the Latin alphabet. Often the time, they're similar or the same only when spelled in the Latin alphabet even. I'm already having trouble memorizing very foreign sounding names such as John Smith. It'd be nice if AMS and others follow the example of APS.